# How restrict access of iphone application after few days?

Tags: ios4, xcode4, appstore-approval, appsettings

My application is to be released in two types in appstore

**1. Paid app
2. Free app**

Free app should be access for 7 days only after 7 days we have to restrict user access application and show a message to access full version (paid app) link.

If is use timer after 7 days i wil show message. But if user delete and reinstall app successfully and again runs. So i want to overcome this problem.

Is it possible?
Please any one help 
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple's app store review guidelines says that:

> 2.9 Apps that are "beta", "demo", "trial", or "test" versions will be rejected

I think it is a bad idea to restrict the use of app after stipulated time. The best thing to do is to let their be only limited set of functionality in the free version and allow the user to buy all functionalities through In-App purchase or the paid version.

Restricting the use of app after some time(or after certain number of launches), may get it rejected by Apple.

Comment: Hi sir is it possible to give only some features and restrict some other features.

Comment: Yes it is possible. Give access to some features, unlock others when users do an In-app purchase